# Crystal reports not showing HTML blank lines

Tags: html, formatting, crystal-reports-xi

I have a Crystal report that is displaying HTML data (can grow, display as html).  I know there are some tags not supported in Crystal (such as bullets), but it seems that line breaks would be supported.

I've pasted the following code into an HTML displayer, and it has a blank line between each statement.  When the same code is displayed in our Crystal report there are no blank lines between.  Can anything be done?

```
> <HTML><BODY><DIV STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Tahoma;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:11;color:#000000;"><DIV><DIV><P><SPAN>This subsite is a 20 cm (8 in) vitrified clay process sewer pipeline about 144 meters long.</SPAN></P><P><SPAN>The second paragraph:</SPAN></P><P><SPAN>The third paragraph.</SPAN></P><P><SPAN>Fourth paragraph:</SPAN></P></DIV></DIV></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Blank lines in HTML != line breaks. Are you using `<br>`s?

Comment: I'm only responsible for the Crystal part of the app -- the example above is something our database would have (C#.net app).  The app and the online html parser do show blank lines.  (See http://www.w3schools.com/html/).  So no, I don't see <br> tags.

Comment: Same problem here... Please help.. I can get page html content as it is but it is not showing as css applied on div.

Comment: There should be no "blank lines", these are paragraph tags with varying top and bottom margin dimensions depending on browser defaults. My guess is that the "HTML displayer" sets P tag margin to zero. It looks like, also, that you can add a stylesheet - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225493%28VS.80%29.aspx.

Comment: It's a moot point for me now, but I was displaying the same html in the same browser, so are you saying that Crystal changes the margin dimensions?  If so, a good answer might be to say how to control those.

Comment: In that case, I did need a solution that would work for other users without them having to do anything special.  But I'll read about that stylesheet, and consider it for next time.